# NS2 installation

Tags: networking, cygwin, ns2

i want to ask about installing NS2 on windows, i used cygwin for that.
i have installed cygwin correctly but when i try to install NS2 i have problems:
creating Makefile

```
creating dltest/Makefile
sed: can't read ./dltest/Makefile.in: No such file or directory
creating tclConfig.sh
make: *** No rule to make target `/home/me/ns-allinone-2.28/tcl8.4.5/unix/dltest/Makefile.in', needed by `Makefile'.  Stop.
tcl8.4.5 make failed! Exiting ...
For problems with Tcl/Tk see http://www.scriptics.com
```

i googled for this problem but i don't find useful result.
Please i want a help for this problem.
Thanks all, and I'm sorry for my English...

Comment: What command are you running that's causing this output? It looks like there's a step being missed to create the Makefile.in...

Comment: @ Al G :i used ./install

Comment: Take a look at the install script and see what should be generating Makefile.in (or is it missing from your install?) and make sure you have it installed in Cygwin.

Comment: @ Al G: Sorry i'm newer user for Cygwin and NS2, how can is be sure from that?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to install ns2 in windows by using VMware. You can use oracle VMware for that and after that install ubundu on VM and finally install ns2 in that, it's very easy and more useful.

Comment: You can't promote self blog/website!

Comment: Oracle VMWare is most useful tool for this

Answer (score 2):

make sure that you have install all required packages: mingw-w32api,gcc4, gcc4-g++ ,w32api,perl,xorg-servers, xinit,libx11-devel, libXmu-devel